# Phonegap (Cordova) image cache

Tags: android, image, caching, cordova

I am developing an app using Phonegap (cordova) and I have the following problem.

One of the app's feature is to create an avatar image where you can select different eyes, hair, skin, etc; a new png image is created and overwrites the old one. 
The problem i am having is that when a new png image is created, i am still seeing the old picture. 
I guess that the old image is cached and when i retrieve the image again (same url), the image is not downloaded again.

What can i do to refresh the image or prevent image caching?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a random string on the end of the url.

Comment: If you suggest random query parameter like someurl?rnd=12345 please state so. puting a random string on the end of an url (no query string) makes a different resource (mostly invalid.)